# how to install wine in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wine

I need to install counter-strike.For that i need to install wine.I have tried using sudo apt install wine.i have checked in the wine website but nothing seems to be working.

---

I re-tried sudo apt-get install wine.It turns out that it actually worked the last time i did it too,except i was unable to click 'OK'(My bad,did not know how to,now i do) in the dialog box.

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the **Ubuntu Software Center** icon on the left and typing `wine` in the search box? This is how you should install **everything** in Ubuntu. Please provide the exact error messages you got previously from `sudo apt-get install wine` command.

Comment: Install aptitude, then run `sudo aptitude install wine` It will likely fail & offers options to resolve. Answer with `q`, then post complete from terminal, if too large for here then use http://paste.ubuntu.com/ & provide link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable the **universe** repository.

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-add-repository universe
```

Open a terminal and execute

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```